# How to stop jupyter r displaying too many rows?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, display

I used "table" and accidentally run 100000 rows in r Jupiter notebook. Now when I open that file, it is stuck. And I cannot run any command in that file. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share your code? And how are you 'displaying' it?

Answer (score 0):

Use head in order to view the first couple of rows of your table

```
head(table(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I waited for 30 minutes and then click kernel-->restart and clear output and waited for another 30 minutes.

Just have enough patience, I guess.